# Geometry shader vertex position to point at camera

Tags: unity, shaders, hlsl, geometry-shader

I have a shader that takes an array of points. At each point, a geometry shader creates a quad oriented towards the camera.

This works fine when the camera and point are at around the same Y value, however, looking up/down upon the billboard results in it shrinking to a point the closer the camera approaches being directly above/below.

[Example](https://youtu.be/niqry--BHRk) (Youtube)

```
[maxvertexcount(4)]
void geom(point v2g IN[1], inout TriangleStream<g2f> triStream) {
    // Calculate some vectors
    float3 up = float3(0, 1, 0);
    float3 look = _WorldSpaceCameraPos - IN[0].position;
    look = normalize(look);
    float3 right = cross(up, look);

    // And how far off-centre our corners are
    float halfS = 0.5f * IN[0].colorScale[1] * _Scale;


    // Calculate verts
    float4 v[4];
    v[0] = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[0].position + float4(+halfS * right - halfS * up, 1.0f));
    v[1] = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[0].position + float4(+halfS * right + halfS * up, 1.0f));
    v[2] = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[0].position + float4(-halfS * right - halfS * up, 1.0f));
    v[3] = UnityObjectToClipPos(IN[0].position + float4(-halfS * right + halfS * up, 1.0f));

    // pass through color texture lookup
    float2 color = float2(IN[0].colorScale[0], .5);

    // Start pushing verts
    g2f o;
    o.position = v[0];
    o.color = color;
    o.uv = float2(1.0f, 0.0f);
    triStream.Append(o);

    ...
```

I'm guessing my issue is related to the fact that my `up` and `look` are approaching coincidence, as the forward derives directly from the camera and the up is in world space, however, I'm uncertain of my diagnosis and unclear on how to generate an appropriately rotated `up`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float3 look = _WorldSpaceCameraPos - IN[0].position;
look = normalize(look);

// TODO: if Look is completely vertical, choose a different up
float3 up = float3(0, 1, 0); 

// Normalize your right vector to be sure it's unit length.
// (Otherwise it approaches 0 length as up and look become parallel)
float3 right = normalize(cross(up, look));

// Choose a new up vector perpendicular to both look and right.
up = cross(look, right);
```